# Does descriptive research have dependent variables?

Tags: experiment-design, descriptive-statistics

I am writing a research proposal for a descriptive study to identify the health beliefs and perceptions among women to mammography breast cancer screening. I am using a Likert scale that is divided into three subsections:

1. Females' perceived susceptibility to breast cancer,
2. Females' perceived benefits to mammography screening uptake, and
3. Females' perceived barriers to uptake of mammography screening.

I was wondering: does a descriptive study  have dependent variables that I need to state in a research proposal? And if I do, would participants' responses to each subsection (perceived susceptibility, perceived benefits and perceived barriers) be the dependent variables?

Comment: Is there some particular hypothesis that you are testing, like whether these "beliefs and perceptions" are related to their having mammograms?

Comment: No there is no hypothesis. The study is purely descriptive. I will be using this Likert scale to identify perhaps negative health beliefs or misperceptions of mammography screening that could then be targeted in further experimental research aiming to determine if educational interventions can change such negative beliefs or misperceptions and the subsequent effect on the uptake of mammography screening. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose that, technically, your Likert scales aren't "dependent variables" because there seems to be no attempt to model them or changes in them in this study.

You should, however, start thinking about them as dependent variables because that is what they will be in your further experimental studies. So your descriptive study should be designed to get a representative sample from the population of interest and large enough to get a reasonable estimate of the variability of responses among members of the population.

Also, purely descriptive studies are not typically so compelling (to funding sources or to the intended audience) as are those with some modeling or interventional aspect. So if you were collecting your Likert scales along with socioeconomic variables, health-insurance coverage, etc., then you might want to model your Likert-scale variables as functions of those other variables. Then they would be "dependent variables." And it would probably be a more useful study.